# Compile a binary file for linking OSX

Tags: macos, binary-data, ld, dylib

I'm trying to compile a binary file into a MACH_O object file so that it can be linked it into a dylib. The dylib is written in c/c++.

On linux the following command is used:
ld -r -b binary -o foo.o foo.bin

I have tried various option on OSX but to no avail:

```
ld -r foo.bin -o foo.o
gives:
ld: warning: -arch not specified
ld: warning: ignoring file foo.bin, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
```

An empty .o file is created

```
ld -arch x86_64 -r foo.bin -o foo.o 
ld: warning: ignoring file foo.bin, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
```

Again and empty .o file is created. Checking the files with nm gives:
nm foo.o 
nm: no name list

The binary file is actually, firmware that will be downloaded to an external device.

Thanks for looking

Comment: you should just need to do something like `ld -dylib -o libFoo.dylib fooSource*.o`. the problem seems to be with foo.bin - if you do `file foo.bin` what does it say?

Comment: The output of file foo.bin is:
`foo.bit: Xilinx BIT data - from foo.ncd;HW_TIMEOUT=FALSE;Us - for 0xFFFFFFFF - built slx16ftg256(011/03/15) - data length 0x31373a35`

Comment: hmm, i'm afraid it doesn't look like the LLVM clang ld does the binary blob embedding that the gnu ld does. you might want to try installing gcc from macports (http://www.macports.org/)? not sure if that'd help, but might be worth a try.

Comment: Thanks will look into macports.

Comment: Wonder if anyone know howto use the -sectcreate option on ld?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's the closest translation to the Linux linker command to perform binary embedding with the OSX linker:

```
touch stub.c
gcc -o stub.o -c stub.c
ld -r -o foo.o -sectcreate binary foo_bin foo.bin stub.o
```

`foo.bin` will be stored in segment `binary`, section `foo_bin` (both names are arbitrary but chosen to mimic GNU ld for ELF on Linux) of the `foo.o` object.

`stub` is necessary because `ld` refuses to create just a custom segment/section. You don't need it if you [link directly with a real code object](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2008-03/msg00028.html).

To get data back from the section, use [getsectbyname](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/Reference/MachOReference/Reference/reference.html) (struct is defined in `mach-o/loader.h`):

```c
#include <mach-o/getsect.h>
const struct section_64 *sect = getsectbyname("binary", "foo_bin");
char *buffer = calloc(1, sect->size+1);
memcpy(buffer, sect->addr, sect->size); // whatever
```

or [getsectdata](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/Reference/MachOReference/Reference/reference.html):

```c
#include <mach-o/getsect.h>
size_t size;
char *data = getsectdata("binary", "foo_bin", &size);
char *buffer = calloc(1, size+1);
memcpy(buffer, data, size); // whatever
```

(I used it to store text data, hence the stringification via `calloc` zeroing of size+1 plus blob copying)

**Warning**: Since 10.7, ASLR got stronger and messes badly with `getsect*` functions, resulting in segfaults. `set disable-aslr off` in GDB before `run`ning to reproduce EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) in debug conditions. People had to [jump through inordinate hoops](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52042) to find the real address and get this working again.

A [simple workaround](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/blob/c600eb8db62cad5dfabc8442b0e8b47d8fe0e0eb/hphp/hack/src/hhi/hhi_elf.c#L122) is to get the offset and size, open the binary and read the data straight from disk. Here is a working example:

```c
// main.c, build with gcc -o main main.c foo.o
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mach-o/getsect.h>

int main() {
    // finding the filename of the running binary is left as an exercise to the reader
    char *filename = "main";

    const struct section_64 *sect = getsectbyname("binary", "foo_bin");
    if (sect == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }

    char *buffer = calloc(1, sect->size+1);
    int fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0) {
        exit(1);
    }
    lseek(fd, sect->offset, SEEK_SET);
    if (read(fd, buffer, sect->size) != sect->size) {
        close(fd);
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("%s", buffer);
}
```

Comment: It looks like there are slightly newer `getsection*` versions of the `getsect*` functions that can be used and which aren't affected by the ASLR problems. Slightly nicer than having to read the raw binary.

Comment: http://gareus.org/wiki/embedding_resources_in_executables also notes that the section name passed to `-sectcreate` cannot be longer than **16** characters...

Comment: So it is done using the GNU's toolchain, and is there a way to do it using apples linker (`clang`)?