# Macports installing binutils

Tags: osx-lion, macports, binutils

I'm trying to install gnu ld, via macports, on Lion.
I have already installed gcc 4.6 from macports. However I need to create elf binary form a binary file,
which I posted as seperate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923097/compile-a-binary-file-for-linking-osx)

I installed binutils from macports, it seems as though everything went fine, however I did get the following message at the end:

```
Warning: binutils installs files outside the common directory structure.
--->  Installing binutils @2.21_0
--->  Activating binutils @2.21_0

Having binutils installed will cause some other ports to fail to build. Consider uninstalling binutils.

--->  Cleaning binutils
```

Looking at the list of tools that should in the binutils packages from [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/)
I'm struggling to find any of them in the normal macports install location of /opt/local/bin

Anyone have an idea as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://trac.macports.org/ticket/24471) it appears as though there is no way to get gnu ld on darwin.